# Visual studio 2012, vc++ - error LNK1181: cannot open input file '*\dllmain.obj'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I get this error message when i try to build the project. I think there is a space in the path specified. I am completely new to VS 2012. This question may be simple, but. Kindly please tell me how do I remove the space in the path? (xxx\ _*space*_dllmain.obj). Or is there an other reason why my build fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6b12xkc.aspx) ? As quoted in the documentation::

**Another possible cause for LNK1181 is that a long file name with embedded spaces was not enclosed in quotation marks. In that case, the linker will only recognize a file name up to the first space, and then assume a file extension of .obj. The solution to this situation is to enclose the long file name (path plus file name) in quotation marks.**

Comment: Well the error was because of the space. I have fixed it. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, and I think I have provided you the same solution. So you can accept the answer if it helped you or is correct to the question you have asked.